# In Jenkins, how to avoid backend log 'org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger'

Tags: svn, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I am using svn plugin in my jenkins, and my jenkins backend logs are occupied by these svn logs. Does anybody have idea how to avoid this logs?

```
Nov 02, 2015 2:24:00 下午 org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger log
Detail: DEFAULT: socket output stream requested...
Nov 02, 2015 2:24:00 下午 org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger log
Detail: DEFAULT: socket output stream requested...
Nov 02, 2015 2:24:00 下午 org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger log
Detail: DEFAULT: socket output stream requested...
Nov 02, 2015 2:24:00 下午 org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger log
Detail: DEFAULT: socket output stream requested...
Nov 02, 2015 2:24:00 下午 org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger log
Detail: DEFAULT: socket output stream requested...
Nov 02, 2015 2:24:00 下午 org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger log
Detail: DEFAULT: socket output stream requested...
Nov 02, 2015 2:24:00 下午 org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger log
Detail: DEFAULT: socket output stream requested...
Nov 02, 2015 2:24:00 下午 org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger log
Detail: DEFAULT: socket output stream requested...
Nov 02, 2015 2:24:00 下午 org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger log
Detail: DEFAULT: socket output stream requested...
Nov 02, 2015 2:24:00 下午 org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger log
Detail: DEFAULT: socket output stream requested...
Nov 02, 2015 2:24:00 下午 org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger log
Detail: DEFAULT: socket output stream requested...
Nov 02, 2015 2:24:00 下午 org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger log
Detail: DEFAULT: socket output stream requested...
Nov 02, 2015 2:24:00 下午 org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger log
Detail: DEFAULT: socket output stream requested...
Nov 02, 2015 2:24:00 下午 org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger log
Detail: DEFAULT: socket output stream requested...
Nov 02, 2015 2:24:00 下午 org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger log
Detail: DEFAULT: socket output stream requested...
Nov 02, 2015 2:24:00 下午 org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.DefaultSVNDebugLogger log
Detail: DEFAULT: socket output stream requested...
```